# Add js in wordpress pages except some of them?

Tags: javascript, java, wordpress

I wrote a code to add a js to specific pages in wordpress. but if I want to: 
 
1- run the code in specific pages how can I change the code? 
2- or run the code in everywhere except in some page IDs? 
how can I cahnge that?

 
thanks in advance to everyone! :D

```
function wpb_hook_javascript() {
  if (is_page ('727')) { 
    ?>
        
<script type="text/javascript">
my script
</script>
    <?php
  }
}
add_action('wp_head', 'wpb_hook_javascript');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be as easy as

```php
function wpb_hook_javascript() {
    if (!is_page(array('the', 'excepted', 'pages'))) {
        wp_enqueue_script('script_name', 'script_path.js')
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpb_hook_javascript' );
```

I used `wp_enqueue_script` because I like it more, but obviously you can stay with injecting it into the head directly, depending on what it does.

Edit: Pretty sure it would work like this:

```php
add_action( 'wp_head', function() {
  if (!is_page(array('the', 'excepted', 'pages'))) {
    ?>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        my script
      </script>
    <?php
  }
}
```

Compare [`logical operators in php`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php), [`is_page`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/), [`arrays in php`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and [`wp_enqueue_script`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/).

Comment: thank you so much but how can I directly add script to this code? like <script></script>?

Comment: Do you not have the option of uploading your js file to somewhere on your server? That would be a better seperation of concerns.